# How to Use SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: select, ms-access, greatest-n-per-group

I have a question about using the DISTINCT keyword in SQL.
I have a table named Customers.  Each record contains
3 fields: CustID, CustName, CustCity.  5 records show 
a CustCity of "Chicago".

I want the SQL results to show just one record for each unique city name.
Also, I just want to see the CustID and the CustName from each record.

I tried this but got a syntax error:

```
SELECT CustID, CustName DISTINCT CustCity 
FROM Customers
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  `DISTINCT` applies to **all** columns in the select list and must be written before all columns.

Comment: I'm using MS Access.

Comment: You want "*the* CustID and *the* CustName from each record"? Which CustID and CustName exactly? If there are multiple customers per city, you must *define* which one you want to show if you want each city reference to show just once. I can't help wondering, though, why you need customer names if your query is about distinct cities.

Comment: I want to select just one customer per city.  It doesn't matter which one.

Answer (score 1):

MS-Access lacks window functions, so you'll need a subquery solution. I think this would work:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM Customers AS c
  INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT CustCity, MIN(CustID) AS CustID
      FROM Customers
      GROUP BY CustCity
    ) AS m
  ON (  m.CustCity = c.CustCity
    AND m.CustID = c.CustID
     ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.* from 
(
    select custId,custName,CustCity,row_number() over (partition by custcity order by custcity) r from customers
) t
where r=1
```

Comment: The OP is using MS Access. This solution won't work in Access.